# Download with php with headers do not work on IE8

Tags: php, header, download, phpexcel

I am trying to download a excel file generated on the fly with php headers:

```
$filename = "assets.xls";
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=$filename");
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

But this does not work on IE8 (but on some other pc with IE8 works???!!). IE8 tries to download the export.php file instead of assets.xls. Any idea why IE8 do this?

Answer (score 5):

Try to format the header correctly [as per the HTTP spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html#sec19.5.1) with a space between `;` and `filename` and quotes around the filename:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '"');
```

Comment: +1 Also, for better experience, consider adding `Content-Length` where available.

Comment: let's try this, but not sure the problem is here. On some IE8 macchine is working on other not.

Comment: Not sure that the problem is there either, but it's obviously wrong as per the spec and may well cause problems.

Comment: I have the same problem. Now the server is running https. Can it be a browser setting?

Answer (score 3):

I have encountered the same problem. And I use the followed method to fix the problem.

```
header("Cache-Control: private");
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
```

Answer (score 2):

I am having a similar issue. I have added the following header before the Content-Deposition header.

```
header("Content-type: text/csv");
header("X-Download-Options: noopen");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"ExcelFileName.csv\"");
```

It seems to work for me. However, you have to save the file first. You cannot open right away.

Answer (score 1):

I have exact same problem! Just got it to work by removing the 'Content-Type' header, so I guess IE8 doesn't play well with that type..? Not sure yet what the best alternative is, but that definitely is the player for me.

Comment: Just got it to work by adding a call to "header_remove();" before starting the normal header calls.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
$filename   =   'Excel_Sheet_'.date('Ymd').".xls";

header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel; "); 
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
ob_clean();
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

After trying to fight with a similar issue for a whole afternoon I discovered that setting

`header("Cache-Control: private");`

Was the best solution.
I had already tried ensuring the `Content-Length`, `Content-Type` and `Content-Disposition` were set and correctly formatted.
The issue is actually that **new IE8 windows and tabs** do not seem to like a download sent through PHP headers the first time it occurs.
When retrying the file after an initial attempt it works fine (in my cases).

After setting the `Cache-Control` as mentioned above all my links have worked without a problem in IE8.

Comment: No one care any more about IE8 (even IE9 and IE10 has been droped by mrcf)

Comment: @albanx My clients do who are still running windows XP! Unfortunately a large number of businesses do still use XP in their offices

Comment: 2 years ago I had the same problem in my prev job. We were able to convince clients to switch to new modern browsers by telling them that will have more features and a faster experience, also more secure. (even on XP you can load chrome and firefox)

Comment: @albanx That is true. I wish everyone I deal with was that easy to convince! Would save me a virtualbox installation for testing for one!